# How to update curl version on ubuntu 8.04?

Tags: curl, ubuntu-8.04, rubygems, extension

On my system 8.04, curl 7.18.0 is installed:

curl --version shows:

```
curl 7.18.0 (i486-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.18.0 OpenSSL/0.9.8g zlib/1.2.3.3 libidn/1.1
Protocols: tftp ftp telnet dict ldap ldaps http file https ftps 
Features: GSS-Negotiate IDN IPv6 Largefile NTLM SSL libz
```

According to https://github.com/toland/patron/issues/25 , I need to install a later version of curl, example 7.19.4, in order to get it to work with patron. What is the process to update curl from 7.18.0 to a later version, example 7.19 or 7.20?

Comment: You should consider upgrading to a newer Ubuntu release, as the LTS support for this version ran out last month.

Comment: @SvW I will consider upgrading some time later, but i want to resolve this problem first and finish a task, i dont want to upgrade because of this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try downloading the curl .deb from the ubuntu package repository : http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/curl and installing it by hand with dpkg:

```
dpkg --install /path/to/curl.deb
```

If you're lucky, the requirements haven't changed too much and it will install without problems.

Comment: wget archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/c/curl/curl_7.19.7.orig.tar.gz, untar, cd, configure, make, sudo make install